# Can I update ApplicationModule and get updated Value on each injection

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Can I change value stored in `Application module` and get it back in new Activity or somewhere else? I've tried this code, I expected that `@Provides` annotated method will calling every time since I call `DaggerExampleBuilder.builde().appComponent(...).build().inject()`

Here is code from my ApplicationModule:

```
 @Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private HandsFreeApp app;
    private Property currentProperty;

public ApplicationModule(HandsFreeApp app) {
    this.app = app;
    Log.d("myTag", "ApplicationModule: "+hashCode());
}

@Provides @Singleton Context provideAppContext() {
    return app;
}

@Provides @Singleton RestClient provideRestClient(Realm realm) {
    TokenDataStore tokenDataStore = new TokenDataStore(realm);
    GetTokenUseCase tokenUseCase = new GetTokenUseCase(new TokenRepository(tokenDataStore));
    return new RestClientRetrofit(tokenUseCase);
}

@Provides @Singleton Realm provideRealm() {
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder(app).build());
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Provides @Singleton Property getCurrentProperty(Realm realm) {

    if(currentProperty == null) {
        BookingStore store = new BookingLocalStore(realm);
        currentProperty = store.getPropertyList().toBlocking().first().get(0);
    }
    Log.d("myTag", "getCurrentProperty: "+currentProperty.getName());
    return currentProperty;
}

public void setCurrentProperty(Property currentProperty) {
    this.currentProperty = currentProperty;
    Log.d("myTag", "setCurrentProperty: "+this.currentProperty.getName());
}}
```

But `getCurrentProperty()` invoked only once

Answer (score 1):

Annotating `getCurrentProperty(Realm)` with `@Singleton` means that Dagger will memoize the result of that `@Provides` method and use it for the rest of the lifetime of that component.  See http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#singletons-and-scoped-bindings.

If you want the method to be invoked each time `Property` is requested, remove `@Singleton`.

Comment: +1. In a case like this, if you want singleton behavior, you'll need to redirect between @Singleton bindings (possibly with a @Qualifier) or use [some other technique to ensure singleton behavior](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#memoize(com.google.common.base.Supplier)).